# Issue with adding a SimpleRNN or LSTM layer in Keras

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am starting to learn RNNs and trying a SimpleRNN implementation in Keras. Here is my code :

```
>>> from keras.models import Sequential
>>> from keras.layers import Embedding, SimpleRNN
>>> model = Sequential()
>>> model.add(Embedding(10000, 32))
>>> model.add(SimpleRNN(32))
>>> model.summary()
```

System throws the following error :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    model.add(SimpleRNN(32))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 187, in add
    output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/recurrent.py", line 500, in **call**
    return super(RNN, self).**call**(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 460, in **call**
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/recurrent.py", line 1030, in call
    initial_state=initial_state)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/recurrent.py", line 609, in call
    input_length=timesteps)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2957, in rnn
    maximum_iterations=input_length)
TypeError: while_loop() got an unexpected keyword argument 'maximum_iterations'

I am using Python 3.6 and Keras 2.2.0. I have tried several things but unable to resolve. Please help.

Regards
Vivek

Comment: Tyy to reinstall tensorflow. I think there is some version problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with `Keras 2.2.0` and `Tensorflow 1.8.0`

Than I installed the `Keras-2.2.0` in accompany with the `Tensorflow-1.8.0 for CPU` by this command:

```
conda install -c hesi_m keras
```

problem solved.

I recommend you to use [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/), which makes life easier.

Thanks